# Atomic Bomb vs Nuclear Missile damage

Tags: civilization-5

Is there a damage difference between Atomic Bomb (AB) vs Nuclear Missile (NM) damage?

I'm up at that stage (rarely) and I'm considering AB purely on the production cost. However, if there is a more-bang-for-your-buck factor here, I may consider NM.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Nuclear Missile](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Nuclear_missile_%28Civ5%29) has upgraded damage, which means that it has a higher percent chance to destroy units and deal heavier damage to cities within its blast radius.  This effect is somewhat randomized, however, and I don't know what the formula is for them, so I can't give you a data-based comparison, except to say that the damage is higher.  The damage is also likely to depend on the power of the units and cities that the weapon effects.

Another factor for your consideration is that [atomic bombs](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Atomic_bomb_%28Civ5%29) are launched from carriers and friendly cities, while nuclear missiles are launched from cities, missile cruisers, and nuclear submarines.  Depending on your enemy's technology level, you might have an easier time getting a sub or cruiser close to the launch site rather than a carrier.  You may also want to account for the production cost of the "transportation unit" if you plan to transport it.

If you're building them to deter, I'd probably go with the atomic bomb, since I don't believe the AI makes a distinction between them when considering your capabilities.

Comment: Today, won my game. first used carrier with Atomic weapons to break through two cities of defence on another island. It was sheltering the main island with the capital. I used Nuclear Missiles on the capital. It razed an adjacent city. These were not small cities. Oh what fun it was.

Comment: Um, there's a missile cruiser? Would this be DLC?

Comment: @avestar101, nope, it's [part of the base game](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Missile_cruiser_(Civ5)).

Answer (score 2):

Atomic bombs have a 50% chance of being intercepted by AA units and/or jet fighters, I believe, while NMs have 0% chance.

Do they both have the same range? I think NM has larger range as well.

And yes, I think nuke subs are easier to sneak close to a coastline than carriers are, but carriers can carry fighters/bombers as well

Answer (score 2):

Nuclear Missiles are capable of completely destroying (razing) cities while Atomic Bombs cannot. Beneath a certain population, as long as the city is not a capital city or a city state then the city will just disappear after being hit. Different sources suggest different population values for this but it is probably true that at 6 pop or below the city will be razed without a bomb shelter and with a bomb shelter this changes to 5 pop. Another source suggests that these values are 4 and 2 respectively, I don't know why this is and I have yet to test but if I find out I will comment the correct values.

A correction to a comment made about atomic bomb and nuclear missile interception:

There is an issue where Nuclear Missiles and Atomic bombs were never made to be interceptable so even though they both have the same evasion stat neither of them can be prevented without killing the stationed bomb or the unit or city that it is being stored in.

Also in response to the same comment, nuclear missiles have 12 range while atomic bombs have 10. Both have the same AoE radius of 2 tiles from the centre. I made this list of similarities and differences for my discord (that's why the formatting might be weird) that I will post below.

Nukes vs Atom bombs:

Similarities

- Both have the same military strength (4000)
- Impacts a 2 tile radius from the centre of the blast
- Evasion and interception is broken and so they cannot be stopped by air and anti air units
- No difference between the damage at the centre or at the edge of the blast
- Cannot be accelerated with great engineers
- UNSURE OF GOLD COST MUST TEST
- Approx half of the pop of the city is killed, this is reduced to a quarter by bomb shelters [citation needed]
- Can rebase to another city

Atomic Bombs

- Unit damage is a random number between 30-70
- Range 10
- Cannot destroy a city
- Requires 1 uranium and 600 production
- Rebases to Carriers

Nuclear Missiles

- 1 shots all units
- Range: 12
- Can destroy cities below 6 pop or 5 if the city has a bomb shelter. Cannot destroy capitals or city states. Uncertain value as another source says 4 and 2 pop respectively.
- Requires 2 Uranium and 1000 production
- Rebases to Nuclear submarines or Missile cruisers

Sources:

- https://civilization.fandom.com/wiki/Atomic_Bomb_(Civ5)
- https://civilization.fandom.com/wiki/Nuclear_Missile_(Civ5)
- https://www.reddit.com/r/civ/comments/21lwpw/unit_discussion_nuclear_missile/